# How to get values from returned anonymous type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, return-type

**I have a method, which returns abstract class**:

```
    public static object CurrentInfo()
    {
        // some code here

        return new
        {
            URL = "www.mydomain.com",
            User = "Jack",
            Age = 20
        };
     }
```

When I use the method, **I obtain an abstract-class result**, so I take it into *object* (or *var*) type:

```
 object obj = MyClass.CurrentInfo();
 //var obj = MyClass.CurrentInfo(); // I also tried that
```

**I cannot access the properties *URL*, *Age* and *User*** from the *obj* object. If I try followings it cause error.

```
 string myUrl = obj.URL // the same form Age and User
```

Should I CAST it? But to what...? I would like to exclude the way of creating a new STRUCT.

Comment: This is not an abstract class, it's an _anonymous type_.

Comment: You can cast to type `dynamic`, but what are you trying to achieve? Why not use a named type (`class`) instead of the anonymous type?

Comment: You could change `object` to `dynamic` and it should work, but this is still misusing anonymous types so you probably should just define a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain the anonymous type, which as indicated makes it difficult to work with, then here is a solution for dealing with the returned object:

```
var obj = CurrentInfo();
System.Type type = obj.GetType();
string url = (string)type.GetProperty("URL").GetValue(obj, null);
```

Comment: You could even put that in as an extension method that takes the object, return type and property name.

Answer (score 5):

Create a class with those properties so you can properly access them then the return object can be a strongly-typed class rather than an anonymous one. This way you can access the properties of the object.

such as

```
public class Info
{
   public string URL {get; set;}
   public string User {get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
}

public static Info CurrentInfo()
    {
        // some code here

        return new Info()
        {
            URL = "www.mydomain.com",
            User = "Jack",
            Age = 20
        };
     }
```

Comment: And of course you can make the new type immutable to mirror the anonymous type's semantics.

Comment: Do you mean by using private/internal/protected set or by the use of a constructor? :)

Comment: The use of a constructor is generally easiest, although not the only, option.

Comment: For sure, it certainly adds value rather than restricting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the type

```
Tuple<string, string, int>
```

This is a named class that represents what you're trying to create, and it's already pre-built into the .NET framework so you don't need to create any new classes or structs.

You would write something like

```
Tuple<string, string, int> obj = Tuple.Create("www.mydomain.com", "Jack", 20);
```

See the MSDN documentation for a 3-argument tuple: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: With this type as the return type in the method declaration, he can use  `return Tuple.Create("www.mydomain.com",
"Jack",
20);`.

Comment: Thanx, this is also a solution, but I needed to work with already written code ;)